# How a when to solve string / date field data type convertion in pojo?

Tags: java, spring, pojo

This question is about application design practice. I am thinking how to solve situation with `pojo` and fields that in application exist in more data types.

In my pojo there is one `Date` field. When creating this pojo by hand I set `Date`, when I parse from XML I have to deal with `String` representation and when make it persistent with `JPA` it should be `Timestamp`.

What is in general best practise in these situation? Should that pojo has this field in two data type representations (`String` and `Date`) or only in one general `Date` and while parsing from String convert it into `Date` from `String`?

Question #2: how to convert this date value from `String` to `Date` - as static method in pojo class? On place it into some external utility class.

Edit #1: I use `Builder` pattern for these pojo-s.

Comment: Agree, this is good question. To be more difficult: Java 8 new better designed date & time package is not compatible with JPA. Jodatime is a winner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like when my domain classes have rich representation of Date - DateTime (joda). Joda provides tons of methods that let you manipulate the date so this is in my opinion the best choice. When I have to write the date into xml or database I convert them.

You're using a Builder pattern so you can provide multiple methods that set the date. For instance:

```
private DateTime createdOn;
...
public Builder createdOn(final DateTime createdOn) {
    this.createdOn = createdOn;
    return this;
}

public Builder createdOn(final String createdOn) {
    this.createdOn = DateTime.parse(createdOn, dateTimeFormatter);
    return this;
}

public Builder createdOn(final Date createdOn) {
    this.createdOn = new DateTime(createdOn);
    return this;
}
```

Conversion between String and Date is just a simple call so I don't think that it has to be separate utility class. The other thing is formatter. It has to know in which format the date has been written into String. You'd probably be using the same format in 95% of cases so I would extract the formatter.